# Determine the speed of the vehicle between these two photos.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I've been sent these two photos from a traffic camera and I've been given an apparent speed (in mph) that the vehicle was going at. I would like to see if this could be double-checked mathematically, but I've been out of school for over a decade and my knowledge of the proper geometry equations and methods are lost to me. So, I turn to you guys to help both with the reminder of how this is calculated and to confirm the vehicle speed.

I've left the relevant information on the image; location, timestamp, full resolution that was provided.

Further relevant info:
-The time between the photos as shown is .4 seconds.
-The make and model of the vehicle is a Ford Focus SE which has a wheelbase of 8'8.3" (104.3")
-The road is in VA, and thankfully the standards for road markings are listed online. [Virginia Supplement to the 2009 MUTCD - Revision 1](https://www.virginiadot.org/business/resources/TED/final_MUTCD/2013_sup/Revision_1_Part_3_Markings.pdf)
-On page 3-3 section 03 the VADOT states that broken line markings are 10' segments with 30' gaps between them.

[Photo 1]
[image: P1]

[Photo 2]
[image: P2]

Comment: Looking at the photos, it appears that the time interval could be anything between 0.3 and 0.5 seconds.

Comment: What was the speed they clocked you at?

Comment: WW1: The timestamp is posted at the bottom of the images. I didn't alter or omit that kind of info. Just personal information.

David Raveh: They clocked me going 45. Which I do know is wrong I was going 35, but I'm likely not going to fight it, I live in a different state and I'd rather not have to travel back to VA to argue my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INITIAL APPROXIMATION :

It looks like the Car back wheel has moved half-way from the tip of a white marking to the tip of the next white marking.
that is $(10+30)/2=20$

Possible time frame : maximum $xx:xx:xx.59999999999-xx:xx:xx.10000000001 \approx 0.5$
Possible time frame : minimum $xx:xx:xx.50000000001-xx:xx:xx.19999999999 \approx 0.3$
Possible time frame : median $xx:xx:xx.50000000001-xx:xx:xx.100000000001 \approx 0.4$

Hence :
$\text{MAX SPEED} = 20/0.3$
$\text{MIN SPEED} = 20/0.5$
$\text{AVG SPEED} = 20/0.4$

Converting to "mph" :
SPEED might be between $27.27$ & $45.45$ , generally around $34.01$

IMPROVEMENT :

(1) We have to measure the Distance between the front wheel Positions & make the calculations.
(2) We have to check whether Car was traveling at some angle & compensate.
(3) We have to ask for further Images & make calculations over longer Durations.
(4) We have to measure the length & width of the Car & using that measurement , we have to measure the road Distance.
(5) We have to measure the wheel movement more accurately via Imaging tools & trigonometry.
(6) We have to ask for Image Meta Data where the time measurement may have more Detail.

These might change the overall calculations by a little to give a narrower overall range.

Comment: I see the back wheel moving a whole dash and half a space, so my estimate for the distance traveled would be...
$$10 + \frac{30}2 = 25$$
That would increase the speeds by 25% resulting in a max speed of ~57 mph

Comment: That's what I got too with some of my calculations in other methods. Mainly using pixel length to calculate the distance of a reference point on the vehicle between the two photos and comparing it to the pavement markers.

As for improvement answers:
2: I can say for certain I was traveling straight on the road. It might not look like it but the road was largely straight and there's construction so I was paying attention to the surroundings.
3: Unfortunately I don't have any further images
4: 172-179″ L x 72″ W x 58″ H
6: I did check and there wasn't anything outside of personal info

Comment: We have "most likely value 35" which is what you are stating & "most unlikely value 45" which is what VADOT is stating. Unfortunately , that is the "Best" we can make up , with minimum effort. With that analysis , you could send email response to VADOT & check whether the Issue can be dropped. Otherwise , you can pay that and move on.

Comment: Yeah, I'm likely to pay it cause if I am to fight it I'd have to travel back to VA which is a pain. This was more for the exercise of the problem and double-checking work rather than proving any entity wrong. Thanks for the help!